# show a div with ng if ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
<div class="navbar-fixed-top navbar-header bar bar-header " ng-if="showHeader">
<div class="container row">
           <div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <h1>ROCK 'N' GRILL<br>
                        <span>Pitampura New Delhi...</span></h1>
                    </a>
                </div>

                {{showSubHeader}}
            <div ng-if="showSubHeader===true" class="topPull" draggable >
            <button ng-if="showSubHeader" class="button-icon"><img src="img/topImg.jpg"></button>
                           </div>      
        </div>               

</div>
</ion-view>
```

The value of `showSubHeader` changes to false but yet I see the div in my view. How do I update view to not show the div when the value is false?

Edit:

This is veiw attached to an abstract state so I believe , the abstract state is not updated when views are switched. How do I reload header when views change or switch?

Comment: Did you try to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Did not help

Comment: Try wrapping your `showSubHeader` variable into other object, ie: `subHeader.show` or something. Angular somehow works differently for variables defined directly and indirectly in scope.

Comment: And one other advice: how is your varbiable changed? Maybe you need to invoke `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: I changed it in a function attached to scope. Also, I tried using $scope.$apply but that did not help either. Besides, I can see the changed value in with {{}} ,just that its not hiding the element from there.

Comment: wrapping in an object did not help :(

Comment: Is your variable a bool for sure? Maybe use `showSubHeader` instead of `showSubHeader===true`

Comment: I tried that as well.

Comment: and yes it is a boolean. It's value updates in the expression as well. Just that div does not update accordingly/.

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html you probably need to let angularjs know that your variable has been updated, by wrapping the code that updates `showSubHeader` in a `$scope.$apply(function() { /* ... */ })`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ng-if` you could use `ng-show`.  So when `showSubHeader` is false, your div won't be shown. Have a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Tried. Did not work. Check the edit. I think this issue is related to the fact that the header is loaded only once. Though I can see the value of variable changing but rendering sticks to the value with which it was initialized.